# Flash message is showing "1" it doesn't show any flash message

Tags: node.js, ejs, connect-flash

**I have a different problem in flash messages, and that is whenever i open my login page with flash message it's show a number "1". I don't know what does it mean.**

```
app.js

const express = require('express')
const mongoose = require('mongoose')
const session = require('express-session')
const expressValidator = require('express-validator')
const MongoStore = require('connect-mongo')(session)
const path = require('path')
const passport = require('passport')
const bodyParser = require('body-parser')
const flash = require('connect-flash')
const routes = require('./routes/index')
const errorHandlers = require('./handlers/errorHandlers')
require('./handlers/passport')

const app = express();

app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname + '/public')))
app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, 'public'))
app.engine('html', require('ejs').renderFile)
app.set('view engine', 'ejs')



app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));

app.use(expressValidator());

// populates req.cookies with any cookies that came along with the request
//app.use(cookieParser());


app.use(session({
  secret: process.env.SECRET,
  key: process.env.KEY,
  resave: false,
  saveUninitialized: false,
  store: new MongoStore({ mongooseConnection: mongoose.connection })
}));

app.use(passport.initialize());
app.use(passport.session());


app.use(flash());

app.use((req, res, next) => {
  res.locals.msg = req.flash();
  res.locals.user = req.user || null;
  res.locals.currentPath = req.path;
  next();
});


// After allllll that above middleware, we finally handle our own routes!
app.use('/', routes);


// If that above routes didnt work, we 404 them and forward to error handler
app.use(errorHandlers.notFound);

// One of our error handlers will see if these errors are just validation errors
//app.use(errorHandlers.flashValidationErrors);


// done! we export it so we can start the site in start.js
module.exports = app;
```

```
userController.js

const mongoose = require('mongoose')
const User = mongoose.model('User')
const promisify = require('es6-promisify')
const { check } = require('express-validator/check')

exports.loginForm = (req, res) => {

  res.render('login',{
  msg: req.flash('error','welcome in login page')})
  ;


};

exports.registerForm = (req, res) => {
  res.render('signup')
};

exports.aboutUs = (req, res) => {
  res.render('about', { title: 'Register' })
};

exports.dash = (req, res) => {
  res.render('dashhome', { title: 'Register' })
}


exports.homePage = (req, res) => {
  res.render('index')
}

exports.contactForm = (req, res) => {
  res.render('contact')
}}
```

```
login.ejs

This is my main syntax of ejs for flash message

    <% if (msg) { %>
    <%=msg %>
    <% } %>
```

I expect the result is 'welcome in login page' but i don't know how i get this output when i open login page and see this result "1" instead of flash message.

Comment: You can check this https://gist.github.com/brianmacarthur/a4e3e0093d368aa8e423

Answer (score 0):

You should assign data to `req.flash` before handling the response  then you can pass the instance of the assigned data when rendering the view.

```
exports.loginForm = (req, res) => {
    req.flash('error', 'welcome in login page');
    res.render('login',{
         msg: req.flash('error')
    })
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Before render the view, You just have to save the local messages using the flash like as below:

```
request.flash("error","Error Occured");
response.locals.messages = request.flash();
res.render('login',{
     msg: req.flash('error')
})
```

Once you set the local messages, you are able to fetch it. Here messages is the main object which as a key called error. So, at the view you may access it like:

```
<% if (locals.messages) { %>

    <script language="javascript">
       alert("<%= messages.error %>");
    </script>

<% } %>
```

You can perform whatever you want under the if condition.